# Shards error msg “can't use localhost … either use localhost or ipadresses”

Tags: mongodb, sharding, mongodb-3.4

I'm trying to set up a a test environment on my pc including sharding. I've added 2 shardservers, a configsvr and a router instance. When i'm trying to add a shard I get following errormsg: *"Can't use localhost as a shard since all shards need to communicate. Either use all shards and configdbs in localhost or all in actual IPs. host: localhost:27017 isLocalHost:1"*"

I searched online and I found a few topics about it but nowhere they explain how exactly and since I'm new to mongoDB it's quiet hard to understand what's going on. I looked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25196942/cant-use-localhost-as-a-shard-since-all-shards-need-to-communicate-either-use) for example. But since I never used anything else than localhost I find it pretty weird.

This is how I set up:

2 shardsvr instances:

```
    mongod --shardsvr --replSet rs1 --port 27017 --dbpath D:\data\db
    mongod --shardsvr --replSet rs2 --port 27018 --dbpath D:\data2\db
```

1 configsvr instance:

```
    mongod --configsvr --replSet rs0 --port 27019 --dbpath D:\datacfg\db
```

I initialised the 3 replica sets (another question, do they need to be all different replicasets? or not?).

Then I added a mongos instance:

```
    mongos --configdb rs0/localhost:27019 --port 27020
```

And then when I'm trying to connect to mongos & addshards it goes wrong:

```
    mongo --port 27020
```

[image: errormsg]

Since I'm never specifying a host I assume that he always uses localhost? no? I don't know how to check anyway. If you need more info tell me.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to add parameters to the ***rs.initiate()***.

For example:

```
rs.initiate({_id : "rs0", version: 1, members: [ {_id : 0, "host" : "localhost:27019"} ] })
```

And that for each node I start. You need to adjust the _id according to the replSet param you're giving with them & also need do adjust the portnumber at the back.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you cannot mix IP addresses and localhost. Those started mongod processes are now using your network device ip-address. If you don't know your machines ip-address, you can check address with `ifconfig` or `ip address` command.

Then if you connect `mongos` using that ip-address instead of localhost. Remember check that your firewall have all those ports open!

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but wasn't my case. I've added an answer what was the solution for me.

Comment: Yes of course you need to initiate every replica set... That is first thing what you do when you start first node of the replica set.

Comment: Yeah, I did that as well, but without the optional parameter. If I use the config parameter, it's solved. I assumed he automatically knew that I was on localhost not any other IP. Apperently not.